# Need a new Tag for linear groups?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

Do we need a new tag for indexing questions about the **Linear Groups** or other related tags like finite groups or permutation groups can cover them well? Honestly, I asked frequently some questions about this kind of groups and whenever I wanted to tag them, I only could index them as finite groups or permutations. If the Masters here feel this is necessary, please do it for MSE. Thanks. :)

Comment: I suppose you know that every user having reputation at least 300 can create tags - see the "How do I create new tag?" section [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags). So the purpose of this question is to ask other users whether they think this tag would be useful, right?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Dear Martin, I am cautious to create a tag here for MSE. I'd like, as you suggested, other tell their opinions about it. I hope it is created soon. :)

Comment: Recently we had here at meta two questions related to creation of new tags. Would it be reasonable to create one big thread for suggestions of new tags where users could show their opinion simply by upvoting, downvoting and commenting? (Something similar as [Tag mergins and synonyms](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms).) Of course, if some of the suggested tags would sparked a lot of discussion, it would be still possible to make a separate thread for it.

Comment: On a side note: seeing that our site has already existed for close to two years, in my wildest dreams I imagine that every time someone creates a new tag or proposes to create a new tag, that person also does the courtesy of proposing a Tag-Wiki-Excerpt.